# Bootstrap Subtheme install issue

Tags: theming

I have gone through the install steps located here: http://drupal-bootstrap.org/api/bootstrap/docs%21Sub-Theming.md/group/sub_theming/8 for a fresh install of drupal 8 with bootstrap, but every time I have come to get the same issue, my navbar looks like this: 
[image]
yet when I set my default as the standard bootstrap theme, everything is perfect. I don't see any errors in my console either.